# WS-Federation protocol is deprecated

Tags: wso2, thinktecture-ident-server, ws-federation, federation

I am working with Identity and Access Control and I want to use Ws-federation protocol to enable browser based SSO (Single Sign On). I want to know whether this protocol is deprecated due to security reasons or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not deprecated. Is one of the main protocols implemented in WIF. (The framework you'd use if you are on the Microsoft platform).

Comment: Thanks Eugenio for your reply. I am worried about it because some of the open source java api not supporting this protocol. They are only supporting ws-trust. I researched a lot for this but many of them are not supporting ws-federation. Is their any specific reason please share.

Comment: From this site i got information please check the column ws-federation   [link]http://www.sourceid.org/ [/link]. I am not sure about this please check once and guide me.

Comment: The way I interpret that message is that Ping has deprecated support for ws-federation in their toolkit. Likely because WIF shipped which is supported and maintained by Microsoft. WS-Fed is a Microsoft centric protocol, it is not surprising that the Java world is not overly enthusiastic about it.

Comment: Ping no longer updates that open source toolkit. You can, however, purchase the Ping product, and get all the support you need.